# move express js app.use () to another file

Tags: node.js, express

I have many routers in my routes folder.
when I want to use them in my main server file, it takes too many lines.
Can i move these to another file? if yes how?

ex:

```
    
app.use("/user", userRouter);
app.use("/user", loginRouter);
app.use("/role", roleRouter);
app.use("/rolePermission", rolePermissionRouter);
app.use("/module", moduleRouter);
app.use("/menu", menuRouter);
app.use("/menuItem", menuItemRouter);
app.use("/news", newsRouter);
app.use("/newsItem", newsItemsRouter);
app.use("/news/category", newsCategoryRouter);
app.use("/news/comments", newsCommentRouter);
app.use("/news/comments/user", newsCommentUserRouter);
app.use("/setting", settingRouter);
app.use("/news/rating/user", newsRatingUserRouter);
app.use("/news/tag/user", newsTagUserRouter);
app.use("/linkbox", linkboxRouter);
app.use("/linkboxItem", linkboxItemRouter);
app.use("/linkbox/category", linkboxCategoryRouter);
app.use("/faq", FAQRouter);
app.use("/faq/category", FAQCategoryRouter);
app.use("/faqItem", FAQItemRouter);
app.use("/contact", contactRouter);
app.use("/contactItem", contactItemRouter);
app.use("/imageGallery", imageGalleryRouter);
app.use("/imageGallery/category", imageGalleryCategoryRouter);
app.use("/imageGallery/comment", imageGalleryCommentRouter);
app.use("/imageGallery/comment/user", imageGalleryCommentUserRouter);
app.use("/imageGalleryItem", imageGalleryItemRouter);
app.use("/imageGallery/tag/user", imageGalleryTagUserRouter);
app.use("/imageGallery/rating/user", imageGalleryRatingUserRouter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement this, but I would recommend to create a new router in between, and register all routes there. Like you already did with e.g the `userRouter`.

You can create a new file `router.js` with the following content:

```js
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();
router.use("/user", userRouter);
router.use("/user", loginRouter);
router.use("/role", roleRouter);
router.use("/rolePermission", rolePermissionRouter);
router.use("/module", moduleRouter);
router.use("/menu", menuRouter);
router.use("/menuItem", menuItemRouter);
router.use("/news", newsRouter);
router.use("/newsItem", newsItemsRouter);
router.use("/news/category", newsCategoryRouter);
router.use("/news/comments", newsCommentRouter);
router.use("/news/comments/user", newsCommentUserRouter);
router.use("/setting", settingRouter);
router.use("/news/rating/user", newsRatingUserRouter);
router.use("/news/tag/user", newsTagUserRouter);
router.use("/linkbox", linkboxRouter);
router.use("/linkboxItem", linkboxItemRouter);
router.use("/linkbox/category", linkboxCategoryRouter);
router.use("/faq", FAQRouter);
router.use("/faq/category", FAQCategoryRouter);
router.use("/faqItem", FAQItemRouter);
router.use("/contact", contactRouter);
router.use("/contactItem", contactItemRouter);
router.use("/imageGallery", imageGalleryRouter);
router.use("/imageGallery/category", imageGalleryCategoryRouter);
router.use("/imageGallery/comment", imageGalleryCommentRouter);
router.use("/imageGallery/comment/user", imageGalleryCommentUserRouter);
router.use("/imageGalleryItem", imageGalleryItemRouter);
router.use("/imageGallery/tag/user", imageGalleryTagUserRouter);
router.use("/imageGallery/rating/user", imageGalleryRatingUserRouter);
export default router;
```

And than import this router into the previous file (like e.g. `server.js` or `main.js`), that you are using to configure the express `app` object, and replace all our previous 30 route registrations with the new router like:

```js
import GlobalRouter from './router.js';

[...]

app.use(GlobalRouter);

[...]
```